# Pandas column layout misinterpreted when 2 columns have same value?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

In a dataset read into pandas with multiple columns two columns have for some rows the same values. When this is the case it seems that the column layout is inproperly interpreted by Pandas

I'm almost a Pandas beginner so I certainly have not grasped all of pandas subtleties but this behaviour is weird to say the least.The dataset is the [2016 kickstarter projects from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/kemical/kickstarter-projects), a zip file where I kept the 2016 dataset, I removed the other dataset. The set does have 12 columns and for a start I'm most interested in the 'main_category' and 'state'. I wanted to have an insight the most occurring main_categories together with the different states 'failed', 'successful', 'suspended' etc.

I used the following code to 'sort this out':

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
ks = pd.read_csv('kickstarter-projects.zip', quotechar='"', encoding='latin1')
ks['total']=ks.groupby('main_category').transform('count')['ID']
ks.groupby(['total','main_category','state']).count().reset_index().sort_values(['total','ID'], ascending=False)
```

There was something strange about the result above however: the state contained the expected values mentioned above, but also some other numeric values. Inspecting the csv file, I found these values coming from an adjacent column, and only the case when the columns 'category' and 'main_category' shared the same values ('Publishing', 'Publishing')

```
    total   main_category state counts->
638 34233   Publishing  live    448 448 448 448 448 448 448 
640 34233   Publishing  suspended   51  51  51  51  51  51  
626 34233   Publishing  0   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   
627 34233   Publishing  1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
```

Changing (globally) the category to something else like 'Pub lishing' in the CSV file, solved it and the numeric states disappeared. This behavior is consistent for other combinations like 'Music', 'Film & Video'. What am I doing wrong or what is going wrong?

Comment: looking at the raw data `ks-projects-201612.csv` i can actually see dirty insert of data, where the data row is shifted across - currency is in the deadline column, deadline data is in goal column - which meant state contained the 'pledge' data (17861) instead of 'successful'
`id = 1105567472` and `id=1106734072`
Could you confirm the data is clean first? you can use `ks[<column_name>].unique()` after reading in the csv to see what the data looks like

Comment: after reading from csv try: `ks.loc[ks['ID']==1106734072]` and you can see that data is incorrect

Comment: @HamzaHaider, Thanks for your effort and analysis, there are quiet some broken records, most of the the time the quoting of the name column is wrong when there are commas. Would there be a way to fix this in the Panda dataset? like "splicing" a row or joining to columns (name & category) when the country column does not have the usual values? Or is this a whole new question?

Comment: I don’t personally have any experience with data cleaning in python - apart from just manipulating the data to the format I want it. If I faced this sort of issue personally I probably woul just spend some time and correcting the data manually - I’m sure someone more experienced in SO will suggest a better solution though. To see which data is coroupt you can do unique values on state column.

Comment: @HamzaHaider I did clean up the data. The CSV was broken: variable number of columns, not well escaped commas etc. After fixing all was well and pandas behaved as expected.

Comment: good to hear @dr jerry :)